# How can I reload the payment section in Magento 2 checkout through JavaScript or knockout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, mini-cart

If reloading is not possible, perhaps triggering a reload somehow?

I wish to update the payment section based on minicart changes. Right now I have an ugly solution by reloading the entire checkout page (payment step) again, which forces the payment methods to reload - but I don't like it, and would prefer an ajax reload.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
require([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information'
], function (
    setShippingInformationAction
) {
    setShippingInformationAction();
});
```

Comment: mmm, and this reload the payment methods?